# How to use Microsoft's Linguistics Analysis API?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to accomplish the ability to use Microsoft's Cognitive Service called Linguistics Analysis. The nuget package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Linguistics does not exist, or at least I am unable to find it when I search for it.

I expect to be able to add the nuget package, however, it is not there. Has anyone tried to use it recently?

Comment: u couldn't find anything by googling?

Comment: Yeah, so all the examples of using it are from 2016, but that was when the nuget package was made available. Although it is on the Microsoft website as a cognitive service available for use, they don't provide the nuget package as it is under reworking. Oh well, I ended up using the stanford parser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a NuGet package ([PCL.Cognitive.LinguisticAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCL.Cognitive.LinguisticAnalysis/)), but it is buggy (I get errors when running `AnalyzeTextAsync`) and its seems it is not maintained anymore.

I suggest that you use the Client Library.

1. Download this repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LinguisticAnalysis-Windows
2. Copy the ClientLibrary project to your solution
3. Use that ClientLibrary (you may need to update Newtonsoft.Json in this project for it to work properly)